# In PHP7 how to tell if I am inside of a class or not

Tags: oop, php-7

I am new to writing OO code, and am still learning the basics.  I think there is likely something simple that I am overlooking but not sure what it is.

I am trying to make a very generic logging system, and have it working when I am in the context of the class.  However I was hoping to use it outside of defined classes as well.  So I am attempting to find out if I am inside of a class or not.  I thought that this might work, but it does not appear to do so.
In this case, LOG_LEVEL is a constant both within and outside of the class.  What did I miss?

```
if ( ! method_exists(self::LOG_LEVEL)) {
  if ( $level <= LOG_LEVEL ){
    // logging code is in here;
  }
}
elseif ( $level <= self::LOG_LEVEL ) {
  // default behaviour that already works in a class context.
```

Comment: i think you need to read more about [method_exists](http://php.net/method_exists) and please provide a full example :)